# Getting runtime(NZEC) error when submitting it on codechef

Tags: java, exception, runtime-error

I am new to programming and this was my first time on codechef. I am getting proper output as required when i run it in cmd, but when i submit on  codechef it keeps saying run time error. Here is my code, can some one please help me. This is the problem: http://www.codechef.com/problems/TIDRICE

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
class Rice
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        String a[][]=new String[20][100];
        String name[]=new String[100];
        String vote[]=new String[100];
        int x,y,j;
        int count=0;
        int flag=0;
        int counts[]=new int[20];
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        x=sc.nextInt(); 
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
        {
            y=sc.nextInt(); 
            for(j=0;j<y;j++)
            {
                a[j][0]=sc.nextLine();
                String[] parts=a[j][0].split(" ");
                name[j]=parts[0];
                vote[j]=parts[1];
                if(parts[1].equals("+")&&(j==0))
                {
                    count=count+1;
                }
                if(parts[1].equals("-")&&(j==0))
                {
                    count=count-1;
                }
                if((parts[1].equals("+"))&&(j>0)&&(parts[0].equals(name[j-1]))&&(vote[j].equals("+")))
                {
                    count=count+0;
                }
                if((parts[1].equals("+"))&&(j>0)&&(!(parts[0].equals(name[j-1]))))
                {
                    count=count+1;
                }
                if((parts[1].equals("-"))&&(j>0)&&((!parts[0].equals(name[j-1]))))
                {
                    count=count-1;
                }
                if((parts[1].equals("-"))&&(j>0)&&(parts[0].equals(name[j-1]))&&(vote[j].equals("+")))
                {
                    count=count-2;
                }
                if((parts[1].equals("+"))&&(j>0)&&(parts[0].equals(name[j-1]))&&(vote[j].equals("-")))
                {
                    count=count+2;
                }   
            }
            counts[i]=count;
            count=0;
            flag=flag+1;
        }
        for(int k=0;k<flag;k++)
        System.out.println(counts[k]);
        }
}
```

Comment: solution you submit should have class name public Main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NZEC means Non Zero Exit Code. 
Specifically, you will get this error in java due to generation of some Exception(a run time error).

try using this format in java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        try{
            //Your Solve
        }catch(Exception e){
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Most probably your code may be generating ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException. Check where you have done something wrong.